How would you program functions for different interrupt requests?
I just finished implementing IDTs and GDTs and called their respective functions to initialize them, but now I'm having trouble finding out whether or not I need separate functions for each IRQ, or somehow the compiler/system can decide on its own which one to call? If it's the former, how would I format my function to let the compiler know which interrupt it is a handler for.
//how would I format this for a specific irq?
__attribute__((interrupt)) void interruptHandler(interruptFrame_t* frame) {
    //do stuff
}


I tried just making a function that prints a line to the screen, but it gave me a warning saying that an ISR should only call functions with the no-caller-saved-registers attribute, so I decided not to compile until I could fully understand what exactly I should do.
